# How pointer arithmetic works

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int a=10;
int *pa;
pa=&a;

int b=5;
*pa++=b++;

printf("%d %d", *pa,b);
```

This gives the output: **6 6**

whereas the following code snippet:

```
int a=10;
int *pa;
pa=&a;

int b=5;
*pa++=b++;

printf("%d %d", a,b);
```

gives the output : **5 6**

why is this so though pa stores the addrress of a?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210109/discussion-on-question-by-venkatesh-how-pointer-arithmetic-works).

Answer (score 2):

The value of the expression `pa++` is the value of `pa`, but this expression has the side effect of incrementing the stored value of `pa` by one element.

After that, using `*pa` is not defined by the C standard: `pa` no longer points to `a` because `pa` has been changed. In the experiment you tried, it looks like `*pa` happened to get the value of `b`, as if the compiler put `b` in memory just after `a` and let `*pa` fetch `b` from memory. That behavior is not defined by the C standard, and you cannot rely on it for several reasons:

- The compiler might not put `b` after `a` in memory, especially if optimization is enabled.
- In some C implementations and/or some circumstances, using `*pa` after `pa` has been modified to point beyond its original object can cause a memory access fault.
- When optimizing, the compiler might, in effect, recognize that `pa` has been changed to be ought of bounds and that `*pa` is not defined by the C standard, and this may result in the compiler transforming the program in arbitrary ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

pa initially points to a. Your code increases pa by 1, which means it points past the variable a. We can ignore everything else you have been doing, because you are trying to print *pa, which reads data from memory past the variable a, which is undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including your program crashing, your program doing something that is obvious nonsense, or doing something that is not so obvious nonsense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210850/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-how-pointer-arithmetic-works).